# Click outside > hide()

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//global vars
var searchBoxes = $(".box");
var searchBox = $(".box");
var searchBoxDefault = "Search...";

searchBoxes.focus(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#searchoptions').show();
});
searchBoxes.blur(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});

searchBox.focus(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value") == searchBoxDefault) $(this).attr("value", "");
});
searchBox.blur(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value") == "") $(this).attr("value", searchBoxDefault);
}); });
```

and html code:

```
<div id="search" class="right">
  <form method="post" class="clearfix">
    <input class="box left" type="text" value="Search..." />
    <input class="button right" type="submit" value="" />
  </form>
  <div id="searchoptions">
    Options:<br /><input checked="checked" type="radio"> Option1</label>
    <input type="radio"> Option2</label>
    <input type="radio"> Option3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is: How can I make when I click outside of #search id, to hide #searchoptions?

I tried with body click, but have bugs...and does not run perfectly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Body click should <s>will</s> work perfectly. Only thing to do is to stop the event propagation. This should work...

```
$('body').click(function() {
      $('#searchoptions').hide();
});

$('#searchoptions').click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

@see http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 4):

Well, since a `click()` elsewhere on the page will effectively call the `$(searchbox).blur()` event handler, you could just add something there to achieve your effect:

```
searchBox.blur(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value") == "") {
        $(this).attr("value", searchBoxDefault);
    }

    $('#searchoptions').hide();

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/krwUS/2/).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is bind a click event to the document that will hide the dropdown if something outside the dropdown is clicked, but won't hide it if something inside the dropdown is clicked

```
searchBoxes.focus(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#searchoptions').show(function(){

        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!clicked.parents().hasClass("class-of-dropdown-container")) {
                $('#searchoptions').hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Then when hiding it, unbind the click event

```
$(document).unbind('click');
```